# How to return list or retrieve object from single class in django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using 2 different classes to perform get and retrieve operations.

```
class Stock(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=StockSerializer
    queryset=Stock.objects.all()

class StockView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self, slug):                    
            collection = Stock.objects.get(slug=slug)            
        return collection

    def get(self, request, slug):
        collection = self.get_queryset(slug)
        serializer = CollectionSerializer(collection)
        
        return Response(
            serializer.data, 
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

but I want to perform both operations from a single class,i.e I don't want to write 2 different classes. So how to handle both (GET & RETRIEVE ) from a single class ?. Can we do that using generic APIViews? Thankx in advance

Comment: You can use `ModelViewSet` instead of `RetrieveAPIView`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: can we user generic API for get and retrieve? Instead of using modelviewset

Answer (score 1):

If you only require GET and RETRIEVE operation then you can use `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet

class StockView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
```

Comment: can we user generic API for get and retrieve? Instead of using modelviewset

Comment: @YoshiHutchinson you can use `GenericAPIView` but then you will have to write a lot of manual code.